# HTML5 boiler plate - "browse happy" message

Tags: html, html5boilerplate

I am using HTML5 boiler plate, and testing the "browse happy" message in IE with developer tools. When I switch to IE7 mode, I don't see the message asking to update browser, I still see the Hello world... Why?

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]--> 

<!-- Add your site or application content here -->
<header>This is a header</header>
<p>Hello world! This is HTML5 Boilerplate.</p>
```

Comment: if you want IE7 to show it, you need to change the comment to `<!--[if lte IE 7]>`. It's set to less than IE7

Comment: you're right it works now.

Answer (score 0):

this change

> if you want IE7 to show it, you need to change the comment to `<!--[if lte IE 7]>`. It's set to less than IE7
>   (by Kalley)

is not coded by default to the boilerplate files